# C code for DDR Access in Xilinx SoC devices

Tags: fpga, xilinx, soc, ddr, xilinx-sdk

In my design, I want to write to DDR and then I want to fetch the data from DDR memory and then pass them to FPGA to be processed, after that, the data will be written back to DDR memory.I am using Xilinx Soc device(ZCU102),It has both fpga an in built processsor(PS).To do the same I need to write a C code for accessing DDR.
So how it is done? What is the keyword used to write values to DDR and to do Memory mapping??

Or if Possible can someone share the C Code for that??

Comment: Use a standard C statement or any wrapper to assign a value to an address. It's the IC design engineers' responsibility to make sure the correct data is written to the correct address.

Comment: @Light Can you tell me what all should be there in that code.I am actually pretty new to this.I don't have any idea of what all should be included in that